C++ Singleton LNK2019 - "Unresolved external symbol (private static) referenced in function (private static)"
Having trouble implementing a singleton class (using tutorial from GeeksForGeeks). I have another class that is implemented the same, however the same issue is not occuring for that class. I have looked at lots of similar questions and tutorials but nothing is mentioning this particular issue, or if they are their solutions are already implemented here (as far as I can tell)
Header file (simplified)
class ActionLogger
{
public:
    static ActionLogger* getInstance();

private:
    ActionLogger();
    ActionLogger(const ActionLogger& obj) = delete;

   static ActionLogger* _instance;

}


cpp file:
ActionLogger* ActionLogger::_instance = NULL;

ActionLogger* ActionLogger::getInstance()
{
    if(_instance == NULL)
    {
        _instance = new ClassName();

    }

    return _instance;
}


Error Message:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "private: __cdecl
ActionLogger::ActionLogger(void)" (??0ActionLogger@@AEAA@XZ)
referenced in function "public: static class ActionLogger * __cdecl
ActionLogger::getInstance(void)"
(?getInstance@ActionLogger@@SAPEAV1@XZ)

Sorry if this has been answered elsewhere, I have looked but sincerely couldn't find it.

don't use Geeksforgeeks to learn. Correct information and code that is worth what you pay for is extremely rare on that site

What is static _instance; supposed to do?  Please show the real code and error message(s).

@G.M. oh sorry that was a typo, thats supposed to be a pointer to the instance of this class. I thought simplified code would be more appropriate because the actual function of this class isn't causing any issues.

"using tutorial from GeeksForGeeks..." That is not a good source to learn c++ tbh. Instead use a good c++ book

Also really try to avoid using singletons.  And if you do NEVER use new to make instances of it (destructor will never get called). What you really should do is create a logging interface (abstract baseclass) and learn about dependency injection.

You haven't defined the default ctor. So defining it should solve the problem.

And if you still stubbornly insist on using a singleton then at least use a Meyer's singleton. ActionLogger& GetActionLoggerInstance() { static ActionLogger logger; return logger; }

@user12002570 yeah i'm realising that. have also looked at the refactoring.guru page for the singleton pattern. geeksforgeeks just came up consistently when finding implementation examples

Note whenever you see a naked new or delete in current C++ you are probably doing something wrong.

@DarthSwashbuckler Try defining it outside the class like ActionLogger::Action:Logger(){} and see if that solve the issue.

please post the code that produces the error. The code you did post will not casue that linker error because it fails before already

@user12002570 Thank you very much that has solved this error. I will look into the meyers singleton + dependency injection, to see about refactoring. thanks for the feedback

Since geekforgeeks is a bad source. Some good resources to learn C++ from are learncpp.com for your initial steps (it is very decent for an online tutorial).
Then use cppreference to lookup everything C++ has to offer.
And finally use the C++ core guidelines to keep up to date with how C++ evolves and how it is supposed to be used.

Aside from the missing constructor, which you could also just declare as =default; I'd generally recommend doing singletons differently:
ActionLogger& ActionLogger::getInstance()
{
   static ActionLogger instance;
   return instance;
}


This forces everyone to go through getInstance, and it's also thread-safe in case you ever get to this kind of stuff.
Also, as you can see, I've changed the return value from a pointer to a reference. It's something I prefer doing to indicate that you always get the object -- if something returns a raw pointer, it's (almost) always because it can be a nullptr to indicate certain kinds of problems.
If you're running into cleanup isses at program exit, because C++ doesn't care whether anyone is still using your instance, you can also prevent cleanup like this:
ActionLogger& ActionLogger::getInstance()
{
   static ActionLogger& instance=*new ActionLogger();
   return instance;
}

In this case, you can actually =delete the destructor, if you want to.
